# What is the different between using a LINK tag in HTML and IMPORT statement in JS file for adding CSS into a react app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What is the different between using a LINK tag in HTML and IMPORT statement in JS file for adding CSS into a react app?

example index.html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='/admin/style.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

VS

example index.js :

```
import './src/admin/style.css';
```

Is there any difference in how the CSS classes are added to the DOM? Also is there any performance improvement if we choose one method over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main difference is the scope of the styles you're applying to the application. 
If you use the link element, the only possibly place to put the style is at the root of the react application, which means all components mounted on the application will have styles applied and inherited from the one style sheet you linked.
In the case of import, it makes it possible to localize some particular styles to a component. For example, if you import a file named `sign-in.css`  to the sign-in component page, only the sign-in page is applied the styles in the style sheet you imported

Comment: this is true if you are importing the `sign-in.css` as CSS module. I am referring to normal import with css-loader and style-loader. In this case I believe the classes still get added to the root of the app.